# Filling a vertical panel with fixed size block and scroll panel

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to have a UI that fills the physical display without scroll bars at the outside and adjusting to different sized/aspect ratio displays. The basic space is divided into 2 vertical panels. One of those panels is intended to have a fixed portion and a scrollable area.

```
    function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  // overall panel to fill available display
//  var container = app.createSimplePanel().setSize("100%","100%");
  // Contains a panel to be divided in two  
  var outer = app.createHorizontalPanel().setSize("100%","100%");
  // Two vertical panels (equal size) filling available space within outer   
  var p1 = app.createVerticalPanel().setSize("100%","100%");
  var p2 = app.createVerticalPanel().setSize("100%","100%");
  // Left hand panel p2 holds two  panels. One fixed height
  var p4 = app.createVerticalPanel().setSize("100%","20PX"); 
  var scrollPanel = app.createScrollPanel().setId('sp').setTag('Empty').setSize("100%","100%");
  // The scroll panel is to hold a variable number of elements and use the space available to display the maximum
  // demonstrated by a vertical panel with label widgets
  var p3 = app.createVerticalPanel().setSize("100%","100%");
  for (i=0;i<100;i++){
    var lab4 = app.createLabel("Te"+(i+4)).setSize("100%","100%");
    p3.add(lab4);
  }
   scrollPanel.add(p3);
  // label to occupy fixed space above scrolled  list
  var lab1 = app.createLabel    ("Testing********************************************************************************************************************************************************************1");

  // label at top of right hand panel
  var lab2 = app.createLabel("Testing********************************************************************************************************************************************************************2");



  p2.add(lab2);
  p4.add(lab1);
  // scroll panel below label panel
 p1.add(p4)
  p1.add(scrollPanel);
  // add some formatting to make panels show up
  applyCSS(outer,_outerContainer)
  applyCSS(p1,_innerContainer)
  applyCSS(p4,_outerContainer)
  applyCSS(p2,_innerContainer)
  applyCSS(p3,_innerContainer)
  outer.add(p1).add(p2);
 // container.add(outer);
  //app.add(container);
  app.add(outer);
  return app;
}
```

(1) What should I do to get the display to divide into 2 equal size panels? The size appears dependent on the relative size of content.
(2) How can I get the vertical panel P1 to maximise the size of the scrollpanel within the physical space available? As coded, the fixed block is placed correctly and the scroll panel  starts halfway down the containing vertical panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of trial and error ... the answers are

(1.1) to use Absolute Panels rather than Vertical Panels .

(1.2) Learn that width and height specifications are about content so you have to allow for padding and margin. Without those the division into 2 equal columns was achieved by  width 50% AbsolutePanel.

(2) Split the first column into 2 using an AbsolutePanel with a  height 30PX and a vertical panel of height 100% (to contain the scrollPanel)
Result ...full width & height display with no scroll bars on outside; scroll bar on scroll panel on pc displays; full width & height display with no scroll bars on outside; scrollable display in  scroll panel (no scroll bar) on i-pad displays in either orientation;